# Azure Connection on Intel Galileo

Tags: c++, windows, azure, intel-galileo, windowsondevices

I'm looking to connect an Intel Galileo to Azure through The Windows 8 version for the Internet of things.

I'm looking to store sensor data such as temperature and humidity in Azure, and have some form of message passing from an app on a phone to the service in Azure and on to the board (and back again).

There are plenty of examples doing this for apps etc, but I can't find anything on doing it with the Galileo. I'm pretty novice when it comes to Azure. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AMQP 1.0 and Azure Service Bus (Event Hubs or Topics). Apache Qpid Proton can be runned on Intel Galileo and Windows 8.

Please, consult [Connect The Dots](http://connectthedots.io) project and its pull requests for more examples.